# Is there a non-hacky way to evenly distribute (taking full available width) an X number of columns in a Y-column grid if Y/X is not an exact division?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Example:

- 3 equal columns taking **the whole available space (33.3% each)** on a 8 column grid?

Is it possible in a non-hacky way somehow?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8,1fr);
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">Item1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use an 8 column grid, use a 24 column one. Lowest multiplier works here.

Comment: Otherwise no there isn't.

Comment: if `width:33.33%` is a hacky way, I don't think so, you also can check `calc(100%/3)` but I don't think it's the best way. @Paulie_D I'm surprised of your 24 column recommandation , Bootstrap use 12 and seems to work well

Comment: @cbdeveloper so you want 8 columns across with 3 equal columns within those?

Comment: @Paulie_D Yeah, the designer suggested choosing different column numbers for different breakpoints. Like: 12 on desktop, 10 on tablet and 8 on mobile. And I'm telling them that maybe it's best to stick with 12 on all devices, because of the possible exact divisions that you get from 12. What do you think?

Comment: You can't do 8 equal columns in a 12 column grid, that's why I suggest 24 columns

Comment: Also you can't do 10 which really complicates things

Comment: @Paulie_D but how can you do 10 in 24? Do you agree the total number of columns of the grid system should remain the same across all breakpoints?

Comment: You can't do 10 as I said. It's up to you if the number of columns remains the same at all break points.